# Why is Echo statement in SQL query not writing in text file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Following code is used for writing a number in the text file but instead it is writing "Echo is ON" into the text file.

```
SET @CMD = 'ECHO '+@Ver+'>'+@Vercheck      
Print @CMD

EXEC xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT
```

Print @CMD gives `ECHO 1>C:\Pharmsuite\Vercheck.txt`

Here instead of `1` the query is writing `Echo is ON` in the text file. What am I doing wrong?